# Pancake Box On Metal Stud with Light Fixture?

Tags: electrical

My basement has metal studs.  Never really worked with those, but when I unmounted the existing light fixture in my basement bathroom I found that there was no box.  As I wanted to move the light anyways it's not a huge deal (other than the code violation).  The metal stud is right where I want to put the light though.  If it were wood I would just put a pancake box up.  Can I do the same thing on metal and just screw into the metal stud with metal screws and hang the fixture on it?

Comment: Do the wires end at the box, or do they go onward to another light fixture?

Comment: End there.  Don't need any box space.

Comment: What is your question? How to mount a pancake box to a metal stud?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes basically.  Is it legal to just use metal screws to screw a pancake box on top of a steel studs and hang a fixture off of it.  If it was wood that is exactly what I would do.

Comment: Please specify what fixture, size and weight

Answer (score 1):

Unless your local code doesn't allow it, you can attach the pancake box with self tapping metal screws.

Do you wiring as per code and you are set.

Comment: Can that support a fixture?

Comment: If it isn't a 30 pound fixture, yes.  The metal stud is also supported by the drywall on top of it.  A normal bath fixture for a ceiling or over a vanity should be no problem.  If you expect to hang a 4 foot diameter crystal chandelier, that's a different issue.

Comment: Nah just a little 2 lamp bathroom fixture